# react-native iOS release build Error loading local images and icon

Tags: ios, react-native

After upgrading my RN version from 0.61.0 to 0.61.2 when i made a release build then it shows error saying that `No bundle url present`. then i delete my main.jsBundle from xcode and create that file again using that command

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

after release build 'No bundle Error' gone but in my release build there is no local images or icon.

[image: after giving release build]

#React-native version info:
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470S CPU @ 2.90GHz Memory: 4.19 GB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash Binaries:
Node: 12.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs: iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
IDEs: Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages: react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2
npmGlobalPackages: react-native-cli: 2.0.1.

Expected Results:
[image]

#My ios folder in my root project
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug in react-native to support ios14 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279

and fixed in react-native v0.63.2
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29237#issuecomment-666940070

**Solution**

- Update react native using https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading.html

or

- Use https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

Comment: yes i have upgraded the version and it is okk but i need the fix in that version.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/huylvdev/react-native-fix-image